# Method "StartUpload" does not exist

Tags: sharepoint-addin, csom, sharepoint-server

My objective is to upload the large files in SharePoint 2013 by using CSOM application.

I am trying to upload the large file in a chunks by referring the available solution and details in [this](https://github.com/pnp/PnP/tree/master/Samples/Core.LargeFileUpload) GitHub project.

> https://github.com/pnp/PnP/tree/master/Samples/Core.LargeFileUpload

But unfortunately when code reaches to this line `ctx.ExecuteQuery();` it is throwing error message like

> Method "StartUpload" does not exist.

The complete lines of code which I am referring are below, kindly look into this and assist me where I am wrong and what are the things I am missing or following.

```
    // Use large file upload approach
ClientResult<long> bytesUploaded = null;

FileStream fs = null;
try
{
    fs = System.IO.File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
    using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs))
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[blockSize];
        long fileoffset = 0;
        long totalBytesRead = 0;
        int bytesRead;
        bool first = true;

        // Read data from filesystem in blocks 
        while ((bytesRead = br.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            totalBytesRead = totalBytesRead + bytesRead;

            if (first)
            {
                using (MemoryStream contentStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    // Add an empty file.
                    FileCreationInformation fileInfo = new FileCreationInformation();
                    fileInfo.ContentStream = contentStream;
                    fileInfo.Url = uniqueFileName;
                    fileInfo.Overwrite = true;
                    uploadFile = docs.RootFolder.Files.Add(fileInfo);

                    // Start upload by uploading the first slice. 
                    using (MemoryStream s = new MemoryStream(buffer))
                    {
                        // Call the start upload method on the first slice
                        bytesUploaded = uploadFile.StartUpload(uploadId, s);
                        ctx.ExecuteQuery();
                        // fileoffset is the pointer where the next slice will be added
                        fileoffset = bytesUploaded.Value;
                    }

                    // we can only start the upload once
                    first = false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // Get a reference to our file
                uploadFile = ctx.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(docs.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl + System.IO.Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar + uniqueFileName);

                if (totalBytesRead == fileSize)
                {
                    // We've reached the end of the file
                    using (MemoryStream s = new MemoryStream(buffer, 0, bytesRead))
                    {
                        // End sliced upload by calling FinishUpload
                        uploadFile = uploadFile.FinishUpload(uploadId, fileoffset, s);
                        ctx.ExecuteQuery();

                        // return the file object for the uploaded file
                        return uploadFile;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    using (MemoryStream s = new MemoryStream(buffer))
                    {
                        // Continue sliced upload
                        bytesUploaded = uploadFile.ContinueUpload(uploadId, fileoffset, s);
                        ctx.ExecuteQuery();
                        // update fileoffset for the next slice
                        fileoffset = bytesUploaded.Value;
                    }
                }
            }

        } // while ((bytesRead = br.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
    }
}
finally
{
    if (fs != null)
    {
        fs.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where have you defined the `uploadFile` object? Make sure `uploadFile` object belongs to `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File` class as `StartUpload` method is in the `File` class.

Comment: @GaneshSanap yes it is defined and belong to the `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File`